# Office Lens without the mobile app?

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive

[Office Lens](https://blogs.office.com/2014/03/17/office-lens-a-onenote-scanner-for-your-pocket/) is a nice app to scan documents and whiteboards to get much better results than just plain photo. Can I somehow use the same algorithm (by Microsoft) on photos that I didn't take myself, e.g., after the photos of a whiteboard come to my email?

The functionality seems to be incorporated to OneDrive so maybe just upload the photo to there? But I can't find a way to force the cleanup process in the web UI.

Comment: Have you tried your idea?   Questions on mobile apps and web apps are not really on topic here at Superuser